# Js / Node.js - How to add an object to object, with a dynamic key name?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I need to add a song to a .json file.
The json is an object, with inside objects.

```
{
  "Song title 1": {
    "title": "Song title 1",
    "author": "Song author 1",
    "date": "1894"
  },
  "Song title 2": {
    "title": "Song title 2",
    "author": "Song author 2",
    "date": "2000"
  },
  "title": {
    "title": "yyyy",
    "author": "",
    "date": "ggggg"
  }
}
```

In the json above was added by running the function `saveSongs("yyyy", "", "ggggg")`

```
export const saveSongs = async (title, author, date) => {
  const songs = JSON.parse(await fs.readFileSync(
    'songs.json', 'utf-8'
  ));

  const newSong = {
    title: {
      "title": title,
      "author": author,
      "date": date
    }
  }

  const updatedBookList = Object.assign(song, newSong)
  console.log(updatedSongList);

  fs.writeFileSync("songs.json", JSON.stringify(updatedSongList))

};
```

The problem is that the key of the object needs to be the same as the title.
So instead of

```
"title": {
        "title": "yyyy",
        "author": "",
        "date": "ggggg"
      }
```

it should save

```
"yyyy": {
        "title": "yyyy",
        "author": "",
        "date": "ggggg"
      }
```

In order to fix that it originall was as a string:

```
  const newSong = {
    "title": {
      "title": title,
      "author": author,
      "date": date
    }
  }
```

so I removed the string quotes... but stil the same.

How can I fix that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To dynamically set the `title` value as the key, use the `[title]: ...` notation:

```
const newSong = {
  [title]: {
    "title": title,
    "author": author,
    "date": date
  }
}
```

---

Also, do not use `await fs.readFileSync` because `readFileSync` *returns* the value. Instead, use `await fs.promises.readFile` which uses promises:

```
export const saveSongs = async (title, author, date) => {
  const songs = JSON.parse(await fs.promises.readFile(
    'songs.json', 'utf-8'
  ));

  const newSong = {
    [title]: {
      "title": title,
      "author": author,
      "date": date
    }
  }

  const updatedBookList = Object.assign(song, newSong)
  console.log(updatedSongList);

  await fs.promises.writeFile("songs.json", JSON.stringify(updatedSongList))

};
```

Comment: perfect answer. for the JS vocabulary nerds among us, this is called a [property accessor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors).

Comment: Note on the `fs.readFileSync` comment. You can import `fs/promises` instead of `fs` to directly import promise functions, then `await fs.readFile()`, although it does remove synchronous functions (`fs.readFileSync()` is no longer included). It could be useful if you only use asynchronous functions.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code :

const newSong = {
[title]: {
"title": title,
"author": author,
"date": date
}
}